# Within a c++ consteval method, is it allowed to refer to the name of a static inline variable to enforce instantiation?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, consteval

Is this valid c++ 20 or does the code rely on an undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>

template<int id>
struct Registration
{
    consteval auto operator() () const noexcept
    {
        // the only side effect of this call is the instantiation of sScope
        sScope.forceInstantiation();

        return id;
    }

private:
  struct Scope
  {
      Scope ()
      {
        std::cout << "Registered value " << id << " before main\n";
      }

      consteval static void forceInstantiation () noexcept
      {
      }
  };

  static const inline Scope sScope = {};
};

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "main begins\n";
    constexpr auto a = Registration<0> {} ();
}
```

This code compiles fine with all three major compilers (GCC, CLANG, MSVC), s.a. https://godbolt.org/z/drszovs5K.

Comment: Looks legal to me, but unnecessary. You can force the instantiation by adding a second static variable, like this one: `constexpr std::integral_constant<decltype(&sScope), &sScope> foo{};`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you very much for this tip. This solves my actual problem in a much more compact and expressive way. Also, it allows me to control whether the instantiation of the static variable is already done by instantiating the template or only by constructing a variable from it. After all, I can define the constexpr variable either as a static class member or in the constructor.